# Scheduler Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, scheduler

Boa noite. Utilizo o *Scheduler* do *Laravel 5.2* para envio de emails e agora estou com um problema. Até sexta feira eu conseguia enviar os emails com assinatura em `img` normalmente, porém na sexta a noite migramos nossos servidores e passamos a utilizar o *PHP 5.6.9* (anterior era *5.5.9*), dai então emails com assinatura não são mais enviados. Alguém pode me ajudar?

**Código da pagina:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Bom dia.<br>
        Seguem anexos os relat&oacute;rios de tempos an&aacute;liticos e desempenho dos operadores da sua equipe em rela&ccedil;&atilde;o ao dia anterior.<br>
        Qualquer d&uacute;vida favor entrar em contato com a equipe de estrat&eacute;gia.<br><br>

        <img src="<?php echo $message->embed('https://intranet.goesnicoladelli.net/imagens/assinatura_intranet.png'); ?>">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Erro informado ao executar a *CRON***

> ```
> [Swift_IoException]  Unable to open file for reading [https://intranet.goesnicoladelli.net/imagens/assinatura_intranet.png]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o código está tentando capturar a imagem "https://intranet.goesnicoladelli.net/imagens/assinatura_intranet.png", porém o endereço dela é inválido.

> ```
> curl -I https://intranet.goesnicoladelli.net/imagens/assinatura_intranet.png
>
> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
> More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
>  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
>  bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>  using the --cacert option.
> If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
>  the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
>  problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
>  not match the domain name in the URL).
> If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
>  the -k (or --insecure) option.
> ```

O problema está na conexão *HTTPS*, pois o certificado é inválido.

Para corrigir você precisa do endereço válido ou baixa-la e transforma-la em [**base64**](https://www.base64-image.de/)

Comment: Correto. Estranho que estava funcionando até a migração... Acredito que alguma permissão foi quebrada.. Valeu

Comment: Acabei de chegar no serviço, vou fazer as alterações agora. Mas acredito que seja isso mesmo..